# Starting remote script/terminal based programs through ssh gives error (Error opening terminal: unknown.)

Tags: ssh

I directly start a remote script/command on an Ubuntu server with the following command:

```
ssh me@server 'nano my_file.txt'
```

However, this throws an error:

```
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

Another example, calling a remote script which  contains the `nano` command from above gives the same error.

```
ssh me@server 'open_nano.sh'
```

When I do `ssh me@server 'echo something'`, I get `something` as expected.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have to use the `-t` flag.

Examples:

```
 ssh -t me@server 'nano my_file.txt'
 ssh -t me@server 'open_nano.sh'
```

Explanation from `man ssh`:

> ```
>  -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi‐
>          trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
>          very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
>          options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
> ```